# Eclipse CDT - C project

Tags: c, eclipse, header, undefined

I'm new using Eclipse for programming in C.
I have several doubts and although I found a lot of questions related to it, by now I don't get to solve my problems.

I have a C project with several source files(.c), header files(.h), a Makefile and an archive library (.a). Until now, I have been editing my code with a editor (gedit) and I have been compiling it with the terminal. I run "make" on the terminal and several shared object libraries (.so) are generated and in addittion, an executable file.

Now, I want to use Eclipse with CDT to programme and compile the code. My first doubt is the type of project that I must choose:

[image]
Executable or Makefile project?

I selected the "Executable" type. Then I tried to build the project and I got a lot of errors due to "undefined references" and several error messages with "relocation x has invalid symbol index".

I did the following steps:

**Properties -> C/C++ General -> Path and Symbols -> Includes -> GNU C -> Add -> Filesystem ->**

I put the project folder, since the header files are in this folder (with absolute path). Then "Clean project" and "Build project". It didn't work, and I got the same errors

Later, I tried:

**Properties -> C/C++ Build -> GCC C Linker -> Miscellaneous -> Other objects ->**

I put the **archive file (.a)**. Then "Clean project" and "Build project".

The previous problems didn't occur, but I got other "undefined references" with files related to the archive file and I can't access them.

I appreciate any help.
I'm sorry if someone already asked this question, but I searched a lot before I write it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I run "make" on the terminal and several shared object libraries (.so) are generated and in addittion, an executable file.

Each .so and each executable should be a separate project in your workspace.